# Limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^{x^2} $

Tags: limits

Given the followning limit:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^{x^2} $$

To find limit I have made following steps:

1. Let $ x = y $ ,then limit equals $0$
2. Let $ x > y $ ,then consider the limit:

$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^{x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{y^2}{x^2}}\right)^{x^2} = 0$$ 
with respect to $$0 < y^2/x^2 < const$$

3. Let $ y > x $ ,then consider the limit:

$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^{y^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty, y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 1}\right)^{x^2} = 0$$ 
with respect to $$0 < x^2/y^2 < const$$

What could you say about my solution?

Comment: Instead of $x=y$ you should say $\displaystyle\lim\left(\frac xy\right) = 1$.

Comment: And for another cases: $0 < lim(x/y) < 1$ and $1 < lim(x/y) < const$?

Comment: "What could you say about my solution?" That it does not suffice to solve the question.

Answer (score 2):

For $x, y >1$, we have the fact that
\begin{align}
2\leq\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)^{x^2}=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}}\right)^{x^2} \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Good fact, thank..

Comment: Do you need $x,y > 1$ or just $x,y > 0$? It seems to follow from the square of $x-y$ is non-negative so $0 \leq (x-y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy$. In order to solve for $2$ we'll need to multiply by $1/y$ and $/1/x$ which should be fine if they're greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**,

Assume $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta, \theta = constant$

Then, the limit changes to

$$ \lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty}\left ( \dfrac {r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{r^2}\right)^{r^2 \cos^2 \theta} \\ \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} (\sin \theta\cos \theta)^{r^2 \cos^2\theta} = 0$$

As expression under bracket is $<1$